# Email date in header (CodeIgniter) is 7 hours off

Tags: codeigniter, email, mailer

When we receive mail from our website, through CodeIgniter first then Google Apps (mailer) - the date in the header is 7 hours behind the real time.

We've checked the server time, and it is correctly set.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may have something to do with this setting in `system/application/config/config.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Master Time Reference
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Options are "local" or "gmt".  This pref tells the system whether to use
| your server's local time as the master "now" reference, or convert it to
| GMT.  See the "date helper" page of the user guide for information
| regarding date handling.
|
*/
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
```